# Sockets c# conectar mediante IP's publicas (TCP/IP)

Tags: c#, networking

Utilizo sockets para conectar dos aplicaciones cliente-servidor, he probado con redes LAN, (con mi direción IP privada, y funciona), con redes LAN como hamachi, entre dos ordenadores diferentes en routers diferentes, y funciona, sin embargo intento probar con direcciones IP publicas, pero no consigo que funcione. ¿A qué puede deberse?

Esto es lo que hago para conexiones en LAN.

`Cliente:`

```
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.10"), 5555));
```

`Servidor:`

```
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.10"), 5555);
            TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);
```

La idea sería, en lugar de hacerlo con direciones de IP privadas (`192.168.0.10`) usar direciones IP publicas, he probado cambiando las direcciones IP, sin embargo me arroja errores como este;

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'Se produjo un error durante el
>   intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió
>   adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en
>   la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido
>   responder 61.33.162.228:5555'

O esta excepción en el lado del servidor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**A MAYORES:**

Los datos los recojo a traves de un stream, leyendo los datos del array de bytes con la función `.Read()`, de la siguiente forma.

```
                client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[100];
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                stream.Read(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);

                string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);

                Console.WriteLine(msg);
```

Sin embargo, también me preguntaba como podría no solo pasarle una cadena de texto, sino poder activar un MessageBox, u otras cosas que no tengan nada que ver con un string.

Comment: Supongo que has abierto el puerto 5555 del router que hace de servidor? Si no lo has hecho te recomiendo que busques el manual del propio router y te informes de como hacerlo.
Un saludo

Comment: ¿Algún ejemplo de port forwarding en c#? ¿Alguna manera de aceptar conexiones que no implique la activación de dicho puerto en el router, o al menos, no de manera manual?

Comment: El port forwarding no lo vas a hacer en el código C#, esto generalmente lo vas a hacer en el Firewall antes de llegar a tu server.

Comment: Cuando envías los mensajes TCP, esos paquetes son manejados por los equipos intermedios antes de llegar a destino y es ahí cuando son redireccionados resolviendo por DNS. El port forwarding se configura en el o los equipos intermedios, no en tu código. Tu código llega hasta decir la IP destino; la lógica del packet switching que conforma la Internet hace el resto

Comment: A qué IP le haces "bind" en el lado servidor? Sospecho que estás intentando usar la IP pública a la que el cliente conecta, pero según dónde tengas el servidor esa IP puede que no sea la de la máquina, sino la de un router que te da acceso. Deberías usar como IP para el bind el valor `"0.0.0.0"` (esto también vale para una LAN). Aparte de eso, el puerto 5555 debe estar abierto en el router y el firewall del lado servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Generalmente los servidores que tienen direcciones IP públicas tienen restringido el acceso por un Firewall.

Normalmente abren los puertos relacionados con http o https (80,443). El puerto que estás intentando utilizar (5555) no suele estar abierto en el servidor o en el Firewall.

Para poder establecer la comunicación de manera exitosa, por lo tanto, solo deberías crear una regla en el Firewall que permita dicha conexión. El firewall puede ser el interno del sistema operativo del server o puede ser un equipo destinado a esta tarea.

Saludos.

Comment: Disculpa la molestia, ¿podría ser posible obtener información más detallada y con algún ejemplo? gracias de antemano

Comment: El ejemplo va a depender de los equipos que estén en frente del terminal con el que quieras establecer la conexión. Algo va de port forwarding en un router casero (que en cualquier foro de torrents o de consolas xbox/ps4 está esa info) a un equipo de seguridad (un WAF) que tiene todo un conjunto de configuraciones relacionadas.

Comment: En este caso son simplemente dos ordenadores con Windows 10 conectados a diferentes routers. Sin embargo no sé si estoy entendiendolo bien, sé abrir puertos desde el propio router pero quisiera poder evitar esa opción. Aplicaciones como Teamviewer, simplemente piden permiso al firewall, ¿como se podría implementar eso? técnicamente no está abriendo puertos en tu router ¿no?

Comment: Team Viewer permite que dos equipos se conecten entre sí a través de un intermediario (El servidor Teamviewer). Este servidor es el que permite que se de un NAT entre los equipos que intervienen en la conexión, pero a diferencia de tu escenario, no se usa una conexión Punto a Punto para establecer la comunicacion.

Comment: @GeorgiaFernández TeamViewer tiene un montón de servidores que hacen de intermediarios y trasladan la imagen del escritorio remoto y las acciones de teclado y mouse, de un lado al otro. Te sugiero que leas más sobre cómo funciona TCP/IP para que entiendas mejor tu problema.

Comment: @GeorgiaFernández ¿Tienes un diagrama de cómo se encuentran conectados cada uno de los dos equipos que quieres conectar? Con eso podría ser más factible dar una mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Por tu código veo que quieres abrir un socket de escucha por el puerto 5555 en un servidor y conectarte desde un cliente.   Como dices en una red local no da problemas (si tienes un Firewall deberías abrir el puerto ántes).

Para que te funcione entre equipos conectados por internet deberías de tener en cuenta el router del lado del servidor.   Este debe tener el puerto tcp/5555 redirigido al servidor en la red interna.

Por lo que necesitas acceso al router para configurarlo.

Si no dispones de ese acceso, podrías usar algo como Open.Nat que te permite abrir esa redirección en el router mediante UPNP.

Buscalo en:   [Open.NAT](https://github.com/lontivero/Open.NAT), tienes ejemplos muy sencillos.

Y un articulo paso a paso en: [CodeProject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/807861/Open-NAT-A-NAT-Traversal-library-for-NET-and-Mono)

Answer (score 0):

Hay una cosa que no aclaran mis compañeros, y es que tu ip publica rota cada cierto tiempo, por tanto aunque pongas una IP hoy que puedes sacar de webs como www.cualesmiip.com, esta acabara cambiando en unas horas o días.

Ahora tienes dos opciones, llamar a tu ISP y pedirles que te dejen una IP estática (por un módico precio) o la otra opción es usar sistemas como el de No-IP (https://www.noip.com/) que te permiten usar sus servicios de forma gratuita.

Otra cosa que deberías hacer es abrir esos puertos en el router (con lo de 192.168.1.1, busca información especifica para esto.), y agregar la excepción en el firewall de tu sistema operativo y de tu antivirus, como te comentan mejor otros compañeros.